# String Delimters

Tags: c++, delimiter

I know this question have been ask many times but most of them just retrieve 1 data. I have a text file that stores data in such a way where it is separated using colon, but then i need to retrieve 3 and 1 data(s) with is separated with 2 delimiters depending on the question.
Eg:
adrian :ee25f924b7df4d4fb93b3da96ee342b1:1

the format is the following

```
username:passwordsalthash:userclearance
```

Is it possible to just extract 'passwordsalthash'? Something like this?

```
do{
        stringstream retrieve(retSalt);
        cout << "Enter username that you want salt to be retrieved"<< endl;
        cin >> rUsername;

       getline (retrieve,gUsername,':');
       getline (retrieve,gSalt,':');
       getline (retrieve,gUserClearance,':');

        inputFile.close();
        if (rUsername != gUsername){
        cout << "User not available!" << endl;
        }        
        } while (rUsername != gUsername);
```

this is how my code looks like, but the program couldnt read the next line. only accepts the first line username and output the last line username

Comment: Did it work for you? If not what exactly didn't work?

Comment: Its not working for me, the code for is totally wrong. Does get line has default delimiter?

Comment: @user3007600: Well, [does it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)? The standard library is pretty well-documented, you know...

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, a look into [the manuals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) would have told you the details.

The usual disclaimer, this code is devoid of the necessary error checking.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs( "shadow.txt" );
    std::string user, pass, clearance;
    std::getline( ifs, user, ':' );
    std::getline( ifs, pass, ':' );
    std::getline( ifs, clearance );
    ifs.close();
    std::cout << "User: '" << user << "'\n"
                 "Pass: '" << pass << "'\n"
                 "Clearance: '" << clearance << "'\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do{
        stringstream retrieve(retSalt);
        cout << "Enter username that you want salt to be retrieved"<< endl;
        cin >> rUsername;

       getline (retrieve,gUsername,':');
       getline (retrieve,gSalt,':');
       getline (retrieve,gUserClearance,':');
       
        inputFile.close();
        if (rUsername != gUsername){
        cout << "User not available!" << endl;
        }        
        } while (rUsername != gUsername);


this is how my code looks like, but the program couldnt read the next line. only accepts the first line username and output the last line username

Comment: @user3007600: Well, look at my `getline` statements, then look at yours, and find what you're doing differently. (Hint: They are not all alike.) Alternatively, read the "Notes" section of the document I linked.